# Filtering JSON and comparing array values

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, filtering

I need to produce a number that is a total number of JSON objects, for instance: "**6** type_A programs in your country".
I have a JSON and have gotten it to filter a the type and country.

each object in the JSON contains a "countries" array (some with many countries, some with only one):

```
"countries":["China","Singapore","U.S.A.","United Kingdom"]
```

The JS:

```
var varCountry = $( "body" ).data( "country");

var programsJSON = (function () {

    var programsJSON = null;
    var a_Programs;


    $.ajax({
       'async': false,
       'global': false,
       'url': '/ProgramListing',
       'dataType': "json",
       'success': function (data) {
          programsJSON = data;
       }
    });

    var find_A = programsJSON.Programs.filter(function(val, index, array) {
        return val.program_type === 'this is A type' && val.countries[0] === varCountry;
    });

    a_Programs = find_A.length; 
    $(".program-count.a_Programs").text(a_Programs);

    return programsJSON;

})();
```

Currently it almost seems to work, it looks through the JSON, it filters all categories that match a_Programs && match a country in the list based on a passed var. Then below it counts the total length and creates a number as a var. This script works but is not accurate -- I think it only counts when the country is === to the countriy listed first in it's array only and ignores it if it is 2nd, 3rd, etc, not sure though.

The problem seems to be here:

```
val.countries[0] === varCountry
```

How it should work: If the country is "China" for instance, I want this to look through the JASON and find the program type && the country array and return the total number of JSON objects that are both a_Program && in the local country.

Comment: never use `'async': false` ! It is a terrible practice and browser vendors have deprecated it. You should be seeing warnings in your console

Answer (score 1):

If `val.countries` is an array, you should be able to use something like this instead:

```
return val.program_type === 'this is A type' && val.countries.indexOf(varCountry) > 0;
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for thanks. Now it won't work in IE11 however.

Comment: `var varCountry = $( "body" ).data( "country");

    var programsJSON = null;
    var a_Programs;


    $.ajax({
       'async': false,
       'global': false,
       'url': '/ProgramListing',
       'dataType': "json",
       'success': function (data) {
          programsJSON = data;
  countList();
       }
    });`

Comment: `function countList(){
     var find_A = programsJSON.Programs.filter(function(val, index, array) {
     return val.program_type === 'this is A type' && val.countries[0] === varCountry;
     });
 
     a_Programs = find_A.length; 
     $(".program-count.a_Programs").text(a_Programs);
 
     return programsJSON;
 
 };`

Comment: I wanted to show the working code that isn't working in IE: Obviously I don't know how to ask questions. I know If I ask another questioin sombody will flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that IE11 doesn't support `includes`. Please see my modified answer.